# Multiple roles definition in Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, roles

I have the following roles definition in Spring Security 4.2.5:

```xml
<security:http>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/doSomething*"
                            access="ROLE_SOMETHING_COMPLETELY_DIFFERENT,ROLE_ONE,ROLE_TWO"/>
    <security:form-login />
    <security:logout />
</security:http>
```

and context fails to load due to the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse expression "ROLE_SOMETHING_COMPLETELY_DIFFERENT,ROLE_ONE,ROLE_TWO"
at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.processMap(ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.<init>(ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
... 79 more
```

I am upgrading from Spring Security 3.2 where the aforementioned snippet was working just fine. The following do not work:

- `access="ROLE_SOMETHING_COMPLETELY_DIFFERENT,ROLE_ONE,ROLE_TWO"`
- `access="ROLE_SOMETHING_COMPLETELY_DIFFERENT, ROLE_ONE, ROLE_TWO"`
- `access='ROLE_SOMETHING_COMPLETELY_DIFFERENT,ROLE_ONE,ROLE_TWO'`
- `access='ROLE_SOMETHING_COMPLETELY_DIFFERENT, ROLE_ONE, ROLE_TWO'`

Nevertheless, this works:

```
access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SOMETHING_COMPLETELY_DIFFERENT','ROLE_ONE','ROLE_TWO')
```

There is no indication, at least from what I have already read, in the Spring Security documentation that such kind of arguments in `access` tag are unparseable. On the contrary there are a lot of [examples using the exact same syntax](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#tech-intro-config-attributes).

I would like to keep the same syntax in the access fields since there are a **lot** of them in the project's access management configuration.

EDIT: Using 4.3.15 Spring Core version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Security 4.x changed the default value of `http` element's `use-expressions` attribute . See [Migrating from Spring Security 3.x to 4.x (XML Configuration)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-http):

> **6.2. Migrate**
>
> The http@use-expressions attribute’s default value changed from false to true. This means if the use-expression attribute is not explicitly configured, then the configuration will need updated. For example, if an application using Spring Security 3.2.x contains a configuration similar to the following:
>
> *Spring Security 3.2.x Sample Configuration*
>
> ```xml
> <http> 
>   <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
>   <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
>   ...
> </http>
> ```
>
> Observe that the use-expressions attribute is not provided. If it were provided, then nothing needs to be done.
>   The configuration will need to be updated to something similar to the following when Spring Security 4.x:
>
> *Migration to Spring Security 4 Configuration*
>
> ```xml
> <http use-expressions="false"> 
>   <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
>   <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
>   ...
> </http>
> ```
>
> We explicitly provide the use-expressions attribute. Again, if the attribute was already provided, then nothing needs to be done.

Comment: I just noticed that the control flow on 3.2 uses `DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource` to parse XML while 4.2 uses `ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource` which corroborates your answer. Thank you very much. This allows me to proceed.